# load calibration file

Tags: calibration, yaml, camera, image-proc, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I would like to calibrate (extrinsically) a Webcam to my Kinect. For that I need the rectified image of the webcam (usb_cam/image_rect). To get that I calibrated the camera like this [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration) and got a ost.txt. I converted this txt file to yaml and saved it.
I use following commands the get the rectified image to run

```
$ roslaunch usb_cam high.launch
```

In another tab:

```
$ ROS_NAMESPACE=usb_cam rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

And then to receive the rectified image

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_rect
```

But when I subscribe to the rectified image I just get

**`[ERROR] [1356567364.021643621]: Rectified topic '/usb_cam/image_rect' requested but camera publishing '/usb_cam/camera_info' is uncalibrated`**

My launchfile looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen">
       <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
        <param name="image_width" value="1920" /> #max: 2304
        <param name="image_height" value="1080" /> #max: 1536
        <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="webcam" />
        <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="file://$(find usb_cam)/usb_cam.yaml" />

    </node>
</launch>
```

My calibration file like this:

```
image_width: 1920
image_height: 1080
camera_name: usb_cam
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1367.163672, 0, 960.12046, 0, 1387.606605, 519.231255, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [0.094896, -0.140698, -0.000646, 0.002101, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [1384.273193, 0, 963.928625, 0, 0, 1410.329346, 518.011368, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

EDIT 1:

I saw that the usb_cam package doesn't use the Camera_Info_Manager. Could that be the reason why the calibration file has no effect? I tried now to insert the calibration parameter directly in the launch file like this. But still no changes....

```
<param name="D" type="string" value="-0.0834232 0.120545 -0.0023918 0.0175383 0 "/>
<param name="K" type="string" value="578.252 0 350.204 0 575.115 207.606 0 0 1 "/>
<param name="R" type="string" value="1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 "/>
<param name="P" type="string" value="578.252 0 350.204 0 0 575.115 207.606 0 0 0 1 0 "/>
```

but still without a change. This is the output for `$ rostopic echo /usb_cam/camera_info`

```
 header: 
  seq: 204
  stamp: 
    secs: 1356617114
    nsecs: 959397246
  frame_id: usb_cam
height: 240
width: 320
distortion_model: ''
D: []
K: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
R: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
P: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51098/load-calibration-file/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the the [usb_cam repository of ccny](http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/usb_cam.git/) which is basically the same but with a working CameraInfoManager.

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-10**:
Dead Link.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure that your camera info url is valid:
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/camera_info_manager/html/classcamera__info__manager_1_1CameraInfoManager.html#_details

Try something like:

```
package://ros_package_name/calibrations/camera3.yaml
```

For you:

```
package://usb_cam/usb_cam.yaml
```

Also, to see if the published topic matches your calibration file.

```
rostopic echo /usb_cam/camera_info
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-12-27**:
I tried this after this post without any change on the behavior.